# How to get num rows from prepared (update) statement executed in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine this code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE courses SET courses_price = ? WHERE id_courses = ?")) {
        foreach ($_POST as $id => $price) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $price, $id);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows === 0) {
            echo 'not affected';
        } else {
            echo 'affected';
        }

    }
}
```

Why num_rows alway returns 0? And yes, I know it counts only afftected rows.. One row is affected always.

Is there a problem with the foreach loop? Or is there a different way how to get number of affected rows?

Comment: `num_rows()` is for SELECT, not UPDATE. You more than likely want `affected_rows()`.

Comment: What? It was SO simple? ... Thank you, can you put it as answer? I will accept it

Comment: *Aye*, pretty much ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What? It was SO simple? ... Thank you, can you put it as answer? I will accept it – kikinet*

As requested by the OP:

`num_rows()` is for SELECT, not UPDATE.

What you want to use is `affected_rows()`.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

From the manual on `affected_rows()`:

Object oriented style
`int $mysqli->affected_rows;`

Procedural style
`int mysqli_affected_rows ( mysqli $link )`